# How to deal with field type changes when using NSCoding

Tags: objective-c, nscoding

I have the following class that implements `NSCoding` and I have created several instances of it and persisted them to file.

```
@interface BiscuitTin ()
@property NSString *biscuitType;
@property int numBiscuits;
@end

@implementation BiscuitTin

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.biscuitType = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"biscuitType"];
        self.numBiscuits = [coder decodeIntForKey:@"numBiscuits"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *coder) {
    [coder encodeObject:self.biscuitType forKey:@"biscuitType"];
    [coder encodeInt:self.numBiscuits forKey:@"numBiscuits"];
}

@end
```

I have now decided that I wish to represent `numBiscuits` as a `float` (as there may be a partially eaten biscuit). Updating the property type and `encodeWithCoder` works fine but when I try to load an existing instance from file the app crashes as it's trying to decode an `int` and a `float`.

Is there a nice way to handle this? Ideally I would be able to load the existing `int` value and convert it to a `float`, but I wouldn't mind just using a default value and not crashing.

I've considered wrapping the applicable `decode` line in a try-catch but in my actually use case there are about 50 or so properties that are being encoded/decoded and it would be nice not to have to have explicit handling for each one that ever changes type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When dealing with this situation myself (and I have a few times), I use  ***versioning***. In other words, encode a version number along with the rest of your encoded data.

Even if you haven't been versioning from the beginning, that's not really problem, you can start now with version `1`, and just treat the absence of a `version` value as equivalent to version `0`.

How?

Store a `version` field in the object you are encoding. Using an `int` or `NSInteger` for this field is probably best.

```
#define CURRENT_VERSION 1
#define MIN_VERSION_WITH_FEATURE_X 1

@implementation BiscuitTin

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        ...
        int vers = [coder decodeIntForKey:@"version"];
        if (vers >= MIN_VERSION_WITH_FEATURE_X) {
            // handle feature X. In your case, decoding a `float`
        } else {
            // handle prior version.
            // In your case, decoding an `int` and converting to `float`
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *coder) {
    ...
    [coder encodeInt:CURRENT_VERSION forKey:@"version"];
}

@end
```

Whenever you add a new feature that is not backwards-compatible, increment the `CURRENT_VERSION`, add a new `MIN_VERSION_WITH_FEATURE_Y` constant with the new `CURRENT_VERSION` integer value, and another branch in the `if` statement within `-initWithCoder:`.

It's a bit messy, but I guess that's the cost of backwards-compatibility. (On the plus side, I think this technique is fairly self-documenting, and therefore it is easy to work with when you return to it months or years later).

Answer (score 5):

In similar cases I've updated the code to save the changed property under a new name. Then the `initWithCoder:` code looks for the new name. If not there, it looks for the old value under old name.

So version 2 of your code (with the property changed to a `float`) would be something like the following:

```
@interface BiscuitTin ()
@property NSString *biscuitType;
@property float numBiscuits;
@end

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.biscuitType = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"biscuitType"];
        if ([coder containsValueForKey:@"numBiscuits2"]) {
            // Process a version 2 archive
            self.numBiscuits = [coder decodeFloatForKey:@"numBiscuits2"];
        } else if ([coder containsValueForKey:@"numBiscuits"]) {
            // Process a version 1 archive
            int oldIntVal = [coder decodeIntForKey:@"numBiscuits"];
            self.numBiscuits = oldIntVal;
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *coder) {
    [coder encodeObject:self.biscuitType forKey:@"biscuitType"];
    // [coder encodeInt:self.numBiscuits forKey:@"numBiscuits"]; // obsolete version
    [coder encodeFloat:self.numBiscuits forKey:@"numBiscuits2"]; // new key name
}
```

Comment: Looks like typo in `else if` for key `@"numBiscuits2"`